# My uiscrollview is not working properly on horizontal scrolling from left to right and right to left

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

my piece of code:

```
 IBOutlet UIScrollView * scrollview;

  [scrollview setScrollEnabled:YES];[scrollview     setContentSize:CGSizeMake(650, 624)]; 

  scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollview.contentSize.width, scrollview.frame.size.height);
```

When I scroll from left to right vice versa the scroll view not back in correct position.What is the right solution for this.please suggest me ideas.

I have put one dropdown named activity and some text boxes inside *UIscrollview* when I scroll horizontally it doesn't retain correctly.

1.first image shows the actual scrollview second,third,fourth images shows the  scrollview not getting correctly like first one. this is my question.

Comment: your question is not clear, you should paste more code and explain more your saying "the scroll view not back in correct position"

Comment: i solved this issue i set width and height of content size same as uiscrollviews width and height example: my uiscrollview width and height is (425,295)  now i set [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(426, 295)];now it works fine.

Comment: @MejdiLassidi  when  app runs it shows the first image such as 1.activity dropdown and text boxes after scrolling it as hide like second and third images...

Comment: if it is resolved , make an answer to your question here and mention that is the right response.

Comment: [1]: http://i.imgur.com/zEU9ttv.png  "actualscrollview"
[2]: http://i.imgur.com/lDk5QwS.png  "onscrollinglefttoright"
[3]: http://i.imgur.com/Owcib7D.png  "onscrollfromrighttoleft"
[4]: http://i.imgur.com/EoXZGsY.png  "onscrollfromlefttoright"

Comment: these are my screen shots just said what do you understand from this...then i will clarify you bro's...

Answer (score 0):

You must be setting the height and/or width of the `UIScrollView` same as that of the `ContentView`. Hence it has nowhere to scroll to, and the UIScrollView is pointless. To solve this, set the height and/or width of the content view(that is the `contentSize`) a larger than the frame of the scroll view. I am just posting a sample code here, edit the values and make it as per your requirement.

```
[scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollview.frame.size.width*2, scrollview.frame.size.height)];
```